# Splitting alphumeric column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, replace, split, alphanumeric

I currently have a dataset looking like this

```
J_J      WMT        MSF
6.7M     167.8M     1.6k
544K     700.7B     875k
888.7B   900K       98.5M
```

I want to split the string values for each column so I could watch something like this:

```
Column1   Column2
6.7         M
544         K  
888.7       B
```

I am currently using the following code for the 1st column:

```
SELECT REPLACE("J_J", '[0-9]') AS Letters,
       REPLACE("J_J", '[A-Z-z]') AS Numbers
FROM   data
```

which gives me the following error:

```
The replace function requires 3 argument(s).
```

How could I declare argument function?,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support `left()` and `right()` and either `len()` or `length()`.  That suggests:

```
select left(J_J, len(J_J) - 1), right(J_J, 1)
```